# trailing return type of deduction guide is not a specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to do an advanced class template argument deduction by using the new deduction guides from c++17. Unfortunately, it looks like you can only use simple template declarations after the `->`, but I need a helper struct to determine the resulting type.

My use case is this one: I have a variadic template class that takes an arbitrary amount of different types. For one constructor I want to specify every single one, for another ctor I want to specify only one type and replicate it N times.

To access this `N` in the deduction guide I introduced a new type:

```
template<size_t N>
struct Replicate { };
```

The class I have is similar this one:

```
template<typename... Foos>
struct Foo {
    // [ ... ] member std::tuple<Foos...>

    // ctor 1: give values for all types (easy to deduce)
    Foo(Foos&&... args /* rvalue ref, NOT forwarding */) { };

    // ctor 2: give one value and N, result is N copies of this value. 
    // takes Replicate<N> as parameter to aid the deduction.
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    Foo(const T& t, Replicate<N>) { };
};
```

The usage would be like this:

```
Foo f1{1, 2, 3.0}; // deduce Foo<int, int, double>;
Foo f2{8, Replicate<4>{}}; // deduce Foo<int, int, int, int>;
```

The deduction guide for the first one is straight forward:

```
template<typename... Ts>
Foo(Ts&&...) -> Foo<Ts...>;
```

It gets problematic with the second (ctor 2) deduction guide. First I need a helper struct to create `Foo<T, T, ... /* total N times */, T>` from `T` and `N`.

```
template<typename, typename, typename>
struct ExpandNTimes;

template<typename T, size_t... Is>
struct ExpandNTimes<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template<size_t> using NthType = T;
    using Type = Foo<NthType<Is>...>;
};
```

Then in the deduction guide I want to utilize the helper to deduce the correct type. I cant directly use `Foo<something>` as there is no kind of "in place parameter pack creation", therefore the helper struct.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
Foo(const T&, Replicate<N>) -> typename ExpandNTimes<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::Type;
```

Unfortunately this results int an error similar to this one:

> ```
> error: trailing return type of 'typename ExpandNTimes<T, /* std things */>::Type' deduction guide is not a specialization of ‘Foo<Ts>’
> ```

Is there any way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is impossible with class template argument deduction - both template names must be [the same](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.guide-3.sentence-3), and the thing after the `->` must be a [*simple-template-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.guide-1). This doesn't leave any room for template shenanigans.

But nothing prevents you from doing the thing that class template argument deduction is intended to replace: factory functions:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
typename ExpandNTimes<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::Type
makeFoo(T const&, Repliace<N>);
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is still room for improvement of deduction guides if they were created to replace factory functions without providing a similar set of functionality. Another missing part would be partial argument deduction. Maybe some day.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable if you can change `Replicate`'s definition to embed a pack into a base class:

```
template<class> struct ReplicateBase {};
template<size_t N> struct Replicate : ReplicateBase<std::make_index_sequence<N>> {};

template<size_t, class T> using Meow = T;

template<typename T, size_t... Ns>
Foo(const T&, ReplicateBase<std::index_sequence<Ns...>>) -> Foo<Meow<Ns, T>...>;
```

Then it's a "simple" matter of constraining everything else to not compete with this guide when passed a `Replicate`:

- `Foo(Foos&&... args) { }` and `template<typename... Ts> Foo(Ts&&...) -> Foo<Ts...>;` (are you sure you want to deduce references when passed lvalues?) should be constrained to when `Foos`/`Ts` aren't `Replicate`s
- `template<typename T, size_t N> Foo(const T& t, Replicate<N>);` needs to be constrained to prevent it from being used to deduce an empty pack (e.g., to when `sizeof...(Foos) == N`)